# how can I generate different different session ID for different users in tokbox

Tags: php, opentok, tokbox

I am working on tokbox video calling.

I need a one to one video calling for different users and psychics. how can I generate different different session ID for different users in tokbox

Answer (score 0):

Think of a TokBox Session like a room. If you want to have a one to one conversation you generate one Session and you give both parties the same sessionId and they will be connected together. You don't need to generate a new sessionId for each participant.

Comment: Thanks adam, Can you please tell me, how can I generate different SESSION ID. Actually now I getting same session id for each. so is there any way, to create a session id for particular user

Comment: @indresh the OpenTok Cloud will generate a whole new session id each time you call `createSession`. Then, you can use database or local hash to associate one session id with one user to achieve your functionality goal.